# WordPress Multisite Root Domain Links & Plugin Setitings

Tags: wordpress, multisite, wordpress-plugin-creation

I would like to create a WordPress multisite because from my understanding a big advantage is the ability to have unique options for plugins per site on the network. However, my goal is for Site B to utilize all other content seen on Site A. E.g. the logo, menu (and it's links), blog, etc. Basically if the visitors lands on Site B and hover above the Home, or About us navigation links or wants to shop for a product I want all those url's to be sitea.com/etc instead of siteb.sitea.com/etc OR sitea.com/siteb/etc

Simply put, my only goal is to have the ability to Enable/Disable certain plugins for specific User Roles AND also the ability to have unique options for ONLY plugins and absolutely nothing else. (An example would be different Min/Max plugin settings for Consumers than Wholesale accounts). That said, is multisite the way to go? If so, how do I maintain all internal be my root domain? If not, what do you recommend for what I am trying to accomplish?

Nothing yet, curious which route and options are best

Comment: WordPress multisite is set up to present separate content (posts, pages, etc) on each subsite.  So your requirement for Site B to use Site A's content cannot directly be met.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t utilise content from another multi site easily/safely and this doesn’t seem like an ideal solution.

In your question you state you’d like different plugin rules for different user types, so based on that I see two options

1. Multisite, but content would need to be duplicated and synced between the two sites. Menus could have fixed URLs instead of page links to the root site, but things like basket functions would be split to each site. Feels like a bad UX.
2. Single site, with some simple use of filters to configure plugin options based on current user.

Depending on the scope of work you might prefer one solution over the other, but I’d be looking at option 2 in most instances.